# GitHub SSH Key Issue - Permission Denied

Tags: git, ssh

Everyone.
I'm so glad to post this question here.

I've been googling so far and I found some answer about this permission issue but they didn't help me.
After generating new SSH keys and adding to GitHub my own Account, this problem is being issued continuously.
I use Ubuntu 16.04.
If you have correct to this question, please let me know.
I'll be happy by your any idea, so please recommend any solution.

Thanks for your time.
Falcon.Guru

Comment: We need more information than that! What steps did you carry out? What's the error message you get? Please update your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohit and gturri.
Thanks for your kind answer.
I've tried these way to solve this issue But they weren't solution.
I just solved this problem. This issue is related to File Permission, not SSH configuration.
I pulled it down with this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 YOUR DIRECTORY URL
```

Thanks Everybody.

Comment: which directory or file did you need to do this for?

Answer (score 1):

**Help, I keep getting a 'Permission Denied (publickey)' error when I push!**

This means, on your local machine, you haven't made any SSH keys. Not to worry. Here's how to fix:

1. Open git bash (Use the Windows search. To find it, type "git bash")
   or the Mac Terminal. Pro Tip: You can use any `*nix` based command
   prompt (but not the default Windows Command Prompt!)
2. Type `cd ~/.ssh.` This will take you to the root directory for Git
   (Likely `C:\Users\[YOUR-USER-NAME]\.ssh\` on Windows)
3. Within the `.ssh` folder, there should be these two files: `id_rsa` and
   `id_rsa.pub.` These are the files that tell your computer how to
   communicate with GitHub, BitBucket, or any other Git based service.
   Type ls to see a directory listing. If those two files don't show
   up, proceed to the next step. NOTE: Your SSH keys must be named
   `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in order for Git, GitHub, and BitBucket to
   recognize them by default.
4. To create the SSH keys, type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C`
   `"your_email@example.com"`. This will create both `id_rsa` and
   `id_rsa.pub` files.
5. Now, go and open `id_rsa.pub` in your favorite text editor (you can do
   this via Windows Explorer or the OSX Finder if you like, tpying `open`
   `.` will open the folder).
6. Copy the contents--exactly as it appears, with no extra spaces or
   lines--of `id_rsa.pub` and paste it into GitHub and/or BitBucket under
   the Account Settings > SSH Keys. NOTE: I like to give the SSH key a
   descriptive name, usually with the name of the workstation I'm on
   along with the date.
7. Now that you've added your public key to Github and/or BitBucket,
   try to `git push` again and see if it works. It should!

   [More info](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're not using an ssh url. To check this, run

```
git remote -v
```

it will print the adresses of your remote repositories. It should look like

```
origin git@github.com:<user-name>/<project-name>
```

If it looks like

```
origin  https://github.com/<user-name>/<project-name>
```

then it's not good. You can fix it with the command

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<user-name>/<project-name>
```